# sum of the product of even positioned digits

Tags: python, algorithm

I have attempted this problem like this :

```
a = input("Enter number : ") 
s = 3
w = 1 
while a>0: 
 digit=a%10
 if n%2 == 0:
     p = p*digit 
 else: 
     s = s+digit 
     a=a/10
 n=n+1 

print "The sum is",s
```

it works perfectly for even no of digits but for odd no of digits like for 234 it shows the sum as 6 and product 3

Comment: Please indent you code correctly. Remember that it's very important in Python.

Comment: This question is based on a false premise. "it works perfectly for even no of digits but for odd no of digits like for 234 it shows the sum as 6 and product 3 whereas it should have been sum=3 and product 8." Odd positioned digits here are digits 1 and 3, their sum is 6, and the only even positioned digit is the 2nd digit which is 3. So you are *supposed* to get sum = 6 and product = 3.

Comment: i think you are wrong shashank...in coding the first digit is zero second is 1 and so on so if a=[234] a(0)=2....and zero is even!

Comment: Is this homework ? It seems a very odd real life problem, and more like a problem set by a course tutor.

Comment: @user166748 If this is a simple problem of 0-indexing vs 1-indexing, you shouldn't be having any trouble. Initialize n to 0 and you're done. Also, 0-indexing does not apply to all programming languages. Lua is 1-indexed and theoretically you can implement arrays in any programming language as n-indexed, where n is any integer of your choosing.

Comment: well 0 indexing applies to python 2.7!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No *explicit* loop:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce # in Python 3 reduce is part of functools

a = input("Enter number : ") 
lst = [int(digit) for digit in a]

add = sum(lst[1::2])
mul = reduce(operator.mul, lst[::2],1)

print("add =",add,"mul =",mul,"result =",add+mul)
```

Producing:

```
Enter number : 234
add = 3 mul = 8 result = 11
```

Comment: i think according the OPs problem statement you should be adding your add and mul values to get your result.

Comment: how do you do this in python 2.7 @SylvainLeroux ?

Comment: cant you write a simpler program using loops. why are you importing something..this program is meant to be done only with loops.

Comment: by the way this program is wrong !!(lst = [int(digit) for digit in a]) in this line it says that the int object is not iterable!

Comment: this question is meant to be done by looping. what is the point of me writing the whole code i attempted when you cant even correct me!?? @SylvainLeroux

Comment: @user166748 The program is correct, `a` is a string in python 3, if you are using python 2, skip the `from functools ..` and replace `input` with `raw_input` to get a string. @SylvainLeroux rewrote your code because it wasn't a good way to accomplish the task, and you haven't specified that you required for-loops. Stack overflow is not a place where people solve your homework, rent a coder for that, but where you discover better ways to do what you are trying to achieve. Read about the [`XY Problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), we answer to `X`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start with n = 0 for this to work

```
a = int(input("Enter number"))
s = 0 
p = 1
n = 0
while a>0: 
    digit=a%10
    if n%2 == 0:
        p *= digit
    else: 
        s += digit
    a /= 10
    n += 1 

print "The sum is",s 
print "Product is",p
```

Comment: in that case if n=0 the for a number having even no of digits there will be a problem.eg-if we take 3456 the sum should be 10 and product 15 but accrding to your code we get sum=8 and product 24. please read the code and question thouroughly!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(num):
    lst = [int(digit) for digit in str(num)]
    mul, add = 1, 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
        if not idx % 2:
            mul *= val
        else:
            add += val
    return add, mul
```

And using it:

```
>>> foo(1234)
(6, 3)
>>> foo(234)
(3, 8)
```

This function will take an integer or a string representation of an integer and split it into a list of `int`s. It will then use `enumerate` to iterate over the list and preform the required operations. It returns a 2 element tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Easy mistake to make about the numbering. The first item of any string, list or array is always index 0. For example, be careful in future to take away 1 from the value returned from len(list) if you are iterating through a list's items with a for loop e.g.

```
for x in range(len(list)-1):
   #your code using list[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the mathematical version:

```
n = input('Enter a number: ')
digits = []

while n > 0:
    digits.append(n%10)
    n //= 10

s = 0
p = 1
i = 0
for digit in reversed(digits):
    if i%2 == 0:
        s += digit
    else:
        p *= digit
    i += 1

print 'Sum of even digits:', s
print 'Product of odd digits:', p
print 'Answer:', s+p
```

I have tried to make this as simple as possible for you.

---

Here's a function that does the same thing:

```
def foo(n):
    s = 0
    p = 1
    for i, digit in enumerate(str(n)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            s += digit
        else:
            p *= digit
    return s+p
```